# No web application option in net beans 7.3

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans-7.3

I have installed NetBeans IDE 7.3. I need to do JSP project from it. But I cannot find a web application option in File -> New Project.

Is there any plugin to install? Or else what should I do?

Comment: Assuming you've downloaded the Java EE edition, its under `Java Web`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you downloaded just the Java SE Edition. Try the EE Edition there:
https://netbeans.org/downloads/

Comment: Do I need to install any plugin? I need to create JSP pages from it.

Answer (score 5):

Simply go to the Tools menu item and go to PlugIns
from there select the tab plugin and search for the Java EE Base

Answer (score 0):

You can get Netbeans with all features using following link..

https://netbeans.org/downloads/

OR

go to "Tools -> Plugins" and download "Java EE Base" plugin from "Available Plugins" tab..